# iPhone: toggle the rightView icon image of UITextField

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

In my project, we are customizing the UITextField for getting the icon image in the right side of the textField(like the bookmark icon in browser).

The functionality is,
1) the textField shouldn't be editable

2) Initially the right icon in black color.

3) IF user starts click, the icon image to be changed to Orange color.

4) If user releases, the icon image turned into its original state (black color)

First 2 points were implemented.
For 3rd point overridden the **UIControl::beginTrackingWithTouch**  method and changed the icon color to Orange.

Requesting your help for implementing the last point.  I am unable to get the release event in order to change the black color image.
Tried using **touchesEnded** but this is called only when release done when user comes out from the control.

anyone help me how to identify when the user click ends.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the user click and hold the bookmark icon ? if yes maybe you can use UIButton for that:

```
UIImage *normalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"normal_image.png"];
UIImage *touchedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"touched_image.png"];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50); // put your frame here

[button setImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // Normal state image
[button setImage:touchedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]; // Touched state image
```

Answer (score 0):

Override below methods:

- (void)endTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)cancelTrackingWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

Comment: **endTrackingWithTouch** is not called at any instance I don't know why?. I have included delegate properly.


**cancelTrackingWithEvent** is called. I have used the same but this is not used for long press. it is called few seconds after the call of **beginTrackingWithTouch**